# Custom view Ribbon Button in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

For contacts entity i have 3 custom views(view 1,view 2,view 3), i want to show a ribbon button in homepage grid only when we selecting a view 3.Is it possible in MS CRM 2011 ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with creating custom JavaScript 'Enable rule' for your ribbon button. [Example here](http://sliong.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/crm-2011-custom-ribbon-enable-rule-javascript-check-relationship/). Create new JS webresource with one function where you will check is specific View is selected.

If ribbon button MUST be hidden, just hide it after checking which View is selected. In this case, I think that this is possible only with modifying the DOM.

Hope it helps!